# Swift 3 Delegate function not called

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, delegates, swift-playground

I'm trying to get my head around Swift delegates and stole/knocked-up a Playground but cannot seem to get the delegate function to be called.

```
protocol fBookDelegate:class {
    func processData(data: String)
}

class fBook {

weak var delegate: fBookDelegate?

init() {
    print("initialising fBook")
    delegate?.processData(data: "hello world")
    print("we should have printed")
    }
}

class fMain: fBookDelegate {
init() {
    print("initialising fMain")
    let getfBook = fBook()
    getfBook.delegate = self
    print("all done let's rumble")
    }

func processData(data: String) {
    print("processing data from fBook with \(data)")
    }
}

var controller = fMain()
```

Can anybody spot my mistake ?

All I get for output is

```
initialising fMain
initialising fBook
we should have printed
all done let's rumble
```

Comment: You're trying to use the delegate in the init of fBook but you don't set it until after you init the object.

Comment: Modify the fBook init to take the delegate as a parameter instead of assigning it as a property afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
import UIKit
protocol fBookDelegate:class {
    func processData(data: String)
}
class fBook {
    init(delegate: fBookDelegate?) {
        print("initialising fBook")
        delegate?.processData(data: "hello world")
        print("we should have printed")
    }
}
class fMain: fBookDelegate {
    init() {
        print("initialising fMain")
        let getfBook = fBook(delegate: self)
        print("all done let's rumble")
    }
    func processData(data: String) {
        print("processing data from fBook with \(data)")
    }
}

var controller = fMain()
```

output :

```
initialising fMain
initialising fBook
processing data from fBook with hello world
we should have printed
all done let's rumble
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option for using your delegate:

```
protocol fBookDelegate:class {
    func processData(data: String)
}

class fBook {

    weak var delegate: fBookDelegate?

    init() {
        print("initialising fBook")
    }

    func talkToMe() {
        delegate?.processData(data: "hello world")
    }
}

class fMain: fBookDelegate {
    init() {
        print("initialising fMain")
        let getfBook = fBook()
        getfBook.delegate = self
        getfBook.talkToMe()
        print("all done let's rumble")
    }

    func processData(data: String) {
        print("processing data from fBook with \(data)")
    }
}

var controller = fMain()
```

Another would be a custom init method that takes the delegate as a parameter.

Comment: Ok maybe I'm not understanding Delegates but ideally I'd like to have it called from fBook when, for example, a button is clicked or a table tapped. Then the object/data/string is sent from fBook to fMain where I can update the UI. Am I going about this the wrong way round ?

Comment: That sounds fine to me.  Basically, all you would do then is replace `talkToMe` with some kind of IBAction method that responds to the type of event you want to handle.  My point, though, was that you need to set the delegate before using it or -- as you saw -- nothing happens.

Comment: Do make sure that your object scope is correct too.  If you want the `fBook` to do things after `fMain` finishes its `init`, something has to keep it alive.

Comment: Still not understanding - surely this bit 

    getfBook.talkToMe() 

Is just calling a function in fBook so how do I move delegate?.processData to an IBAction ?

Comment: Create the IBAction method in fBook and copy that line into it?  (Sorry, I don't know how to make it simpler and don't know what's confusing you.)

Comment: Yes but if I move the delegate?.processData(data: "hello world") to an IBAction and removed func talkToMe() then in fMain getfBook.talkToMe() would not exist. Anyway it looks like Delegate won't work for what I want so I'm going back to NSNotification but thanks for your help.